# The Artificial Intelligence beta has started!

Tags: discussion

After previous [failures](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/), the [AI site](http://ai.stackexchange.com) has its probably last chance to join the SE network. GDSE has its own [ai](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) tag but if you're interested AI beyond gaming (e.g. the process behind this, or AI for playing board games), you're more than welcome to join.

Currently we need your help, since the site is struggling to find its own distinct and unique scope.

Address: [http://ai.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit) (to access go [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence) and click the 'visit' link)

We've already few question related to [gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming), like chess or Go.

I hope you find this information interesting.

Comment: I can guarantee, that there will be someone who makes an artifical intelligence just to post questions on the AISE

Comment: Have you considered setting up a community promotion ad?

Comment: @JoshPetrie The site entered recently private beta, so it has no banner yet and the site is risking to be closed in few days, so after it goes public, then yes, otherwise you won't be able to visit the site which is in private beta by clicking on the banner.

Comment: There's a pretty big difference in academic AI and game AI. Does the AI site actually cover both?

Comment: @Byte56 The scope is still being discussed. Basically everything related to AI what's not covered on the other sites, but some overlap could be expected. Game AI is already at gamedev.SE, some other at Stats.SE, DataScience, cstheory.se, basically AI topics are spread across already 10-20 sites, so there is some talk about having one central point, otherwise it's very confusing. But dev gaming AI is on-topic only here I guess, not likely there.